# datatable is not showing data, possible issue with browser

Tags: javascript, browser, datatable

i've been working on datatables for long time with updating and adding records with no errors, but sudden it doesn't displayed data only showing table headings. after searching from net i found there could be browser's cache/history issue. i also removed it, even it's not showing any error at console. There is no any issue in my script but possible external issue. Any guidance for this issue ?

Comment: Can you show us any code that you have written for the datatable?

Comment: there is no any issue with my script i just turned off and then restarted my laptop and it didn't displayed any data,, but it's working on other's system..

Comment: What browser is it not working with?  Have you tried other browsers?  Sounds like the issue is just with your laptop, is that correct?

Comment: issue not with my laptop but with browser,, and i've tried with chrome and mozilla,,

Comment: You suggested that other systems are working.  What is different between the working and non-working computers.

Comment: Was this issue resolved? I'm experiencing the same problem with Chrome on some machines

Comment: @Adrian if you are running on live server add www with your domain or just check custom.js file where your js file of datatable is available